# How to fix a text file wrt to punctuation?

Tags: java, text, stream

I am currently working on an independent project, but I am having trouble converting a text file into the proper format. Currently, my program reads a new line -- it assumes a line = a sentence -- but this is problematic since someone could just insert a paragraph where punctuation is scattered all over the place. What I want to do is make each sentence become its individual line and then read from that file. I didn't want to come empty so I tried it the only way I could and I got it to work with short-length strings, but once I get into longer text files I had to use Streams and I came into issues: (File name too long)

---

Example:

Input: This is a dummy sentence. Hello this is one too. And this one too.

Output:

This is a dummy sentence.

Hello this is one too.

And this one too.

---

This is working

---

```
public static void main(String args[])
            {
            String text = "Joanne had one requirement: Her child must be" +
                         " adopted by college graduates. So the doctor arranged" +
                            "for the baby to be placed with a lawyer and his wife." + 
                            " Paul and Clara named their new baby Steven Paul Jobs.";    
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\?|\\.|\\!|\\¡|\\¿");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
            StringBuilder text_fixed = new StringBuilder(); 
            String withline = ""; 
            int starter = 0; 
            String overall = "";
            String blankspace = " ";

            while (matcher.find()) 
            {
                int holder = matcher.start(); 
                System.out.println("=========> " + holder);

                /***/

                withline = text.substring(starter, holder + 1); 
                withline = withline + "\r\n";
                overall = overall + withline; 
                System.out.println(withline);
                starter = holder + 2;


            }
                System.out.println(overall);
                //return overall;
            }
```

---

This gets issues:

```
                public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
                {
                    final String INPUT_FILE = "practice.txt";
                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(INPUT_FILE);
                    String fixread = getStringFromInputStream(in);
                   String fixedspace =  fixme(fixread);
                    File ins = new File(fixedspace);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ins));
                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\n");
                    String line, sentence;
                    String[] t;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null )
                    {
                        t = p.split(line);  /**hold curr sentence and remove it from OG txt file since you will reread.*/
                        sentence = t[0]; 
                        indiv_sentences.add(sentence);   
                    }
                    //putSentencestoTrie(indiv_sentences);
                    //runAutocompletealt();
                }



            private static String fixme(String fixread) 
            {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\?|\\.|\\!|\\¡|\\¿");
                String actString = fixread.toString();
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(actString);
                String withline = ""; 
                int starter = 0; 
                String overall = "";
                while (matcher.find()) 
                {
                    int holder = matcher.start(); 
                    withline = actString.substring(starter, holder + 1); 
                    withline = withline + "\r\n";
                    overall = overall + withline; 
                    starter = holder + 2;
                }

                    return overall;
                }

            /**this is not my code, this was provided by an outside source, I do not take credit*/
            /**http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-string-in-java/*/
            private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

                BufferedReader br = null;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line;
                try {

                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (br != null) {
                        try {
                            br.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return sb.toString();

            }
```

---

---

https://github.com/ChristianCSE/Phrase-Finder

I am pretty sure this is all the code I use for this section, but if you need to see the rest of my code I provided a link to my repository. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Just replace "." with new line ?!

Comment: That's what I do with the basic case, but once I get to input text cases it doesn't work. The first method is doing what you have advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are creating the file with name that supposed to be its content-which is too long for a filename.

```
 String fixedspace =  fixme(fixread);
 File ins = new File(fixedspace);//this is the issue, you gave the content as its name
```

Try to give a sample name and write output to the file.One sample is below.

```
String fixedspace =  fixme(fixread);
File out= new File("output.txt");
FileWriter  fr = new FileWriter(out);
fr.write(fixedspace);
```

Then read it and continue.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've never really dealt with Reading and Writing to files in Java -- I've only done it in C -- and I didn't really understand it until now. Thanks! It works now!